# How to get data from DoubleClick view using API?

Tags: google-api, report, double-click-advertising

I need to find view by name (or recreate it), request file and download it. Via GUI, I can do it all right:

[image: Screenshot]

Sadly, I don't know how to get it by API. Looks for me that I need keyword report, because Keyword column is most important for me, as it allows me to connect entries to Facebook report.

Now, this views are not DFA reports, because [`dfareporting.reports.list`](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/dfareporting/v2.3/dfareporting.reports.list) returns:

```
{
 "kind": "dfareporting#reportList",
 "etag": "\" some etag I won't share \"",
 "nextPageToken": "",
 "items": [
 ]
}
```

Empty list. So if there are reports, they are not shared with me. Yes, app is using my profile ID, the same one I use to view stings in GUI.

So, I may try to create report with data I need using [`dfareporting.reports.insert`](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/dfareporting/v2.3/dfareporting.reports.insert), but then for both `"type":"keyword"` and `"type":"keywords"` I get:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid value for: keywords is not a valid value"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid value for: keywords is not a valid value"
 }
}
```

I could try methods from `dfareporting.ads` set, but keywords are set on ad groups / ad sets (sadly, it was communicated to me in my native tongue, not in English), not on ads directly, so this is no help for me.

How can I get this data via code? What am I missing? It seems to be something big and obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this report for seller:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/adexchangeseller/v2.0/accounts/accountId/reports
```

**Path parameters**

- accountId | string | Account which owns the generated report.

**Required query parameters**

- endDate   | string    | End of the date range to report on in "YYYY-MM-DD" format, inclusive.
- startDate | string    | Start of the date range to report on in "YYYY-MM-DD" format, inclusive.

**Optional query parameters**

- dimension | string    | Dimensions to base the report on.
- filter    | string    | Filters to be run on the report.
- locale    | string    | Optional locale to use for translating report output to a local language. Defaults to "en_US" if not specified.
- maxResults    | unsigned integer  | The maximum number of rows of report data to return. Acceptable values are 0 to 50000, inclusive.
- metric    | string    | Numeric columns to include in the report.
- sort  | string    | The name of a dimension or metric to sort the resulting report on, optionally prefixed with "+" to sort ascending or "-" to sort descending. If no prefix is specified, the column is sorted ascending.
- startIndex    | unsigned integer  | Index of the first row of report data to return. Acceptable values are 0 to 5000, inclusive.